# Can't link existing FaceBook page with new created FaceBook App

Tags: android, ios, facebook, mobile, sdk

***Can't Linking existing FaceBook page to new created app.*** The Page created 1-2 years ago.

I have 30 page some of them can't link with existing Facebook app

If page settings like this it can't link

[image]

The page have selected tabs

> General
>
> Messaging
>
> Post Attributes
>
> Notifications
>
> Page Roles
>
> People and Other Pages
>
> Apps
>
> Instagram Ads
>
> Featured
>
> Page Support
>
> Active Log

If page settings like this it is possible

[image]

> General
>
> Messaging
>
> **Page Info**
>
> Post Attributes
>
> Notifications
>
> Page Roles
>
> People and Other Pages
>
> **Preferred Page Audience**
>
> Apps
>
> Instagram Ads
>
> Featured
>
> Page Support
>
> Active Log

---

If in Page Settings there is not **Preferred Page Audience** and **Page Info**
That is mean (in my case) can't choose existing page. In Facebook Developer app details.

[https://developers.facebook.com/apps/MY_APP_ID/app-details/](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/543830732395447/app-details/)

[image]

If **Preferred Page Audience** and **Page Info** is not hidden then all ok, I can choose existing page.

https://developers.facebook.com/apps/MY_APP_ID/app-details/

[image]

Both are have some category. ***Brands & Products : App Page***

Please see attaches screenshots. They are have some category "***Brands & Products : App Page***"

***In my case in both case the FaceBook App name and Facebook Page name is some, there is not problem with name, I think so***

Page 1

[image]

Page 2
[image]

How I can fix issue

Comment: I edited the question don't have like that problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found one answer for Facebook link with existing page

Categorize your existing page under "Facebook App Page" with "Brands & Products" category.

Change your page name to mach your Facebook App name.

Go to your App and select "Facebook App Details"

Under "Facebook App Contact Info" you will find "Facebook App Page". There you will be able to create a new page or if all went well, select your page from a list.

I found the info in the little question-mark next to "Facebook App page".

Answer (score 1):

Change your page name to match your Facebook App name but make sure it's exactly the same... I didn't have a space in between two words and it took me hours of frustration to find out it needed to be the exact same name on the app and page name. Page url name is irrelevant.